# Can I obfuscate javascript build apps?

Tags: codenameone

I try to build a javascript build on codenameone. But I still can see the class name in the built files set, from teavm.

Is there anyway to obfuscate the all class name in my package? I realize android build is obfuscated by default, not sure how is javascript build.

Kindly advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already obfuscated by default e.g. check out the restaurant demo from the [demos section](https://www.codenameone.com/demos.html).

The JavaScript code is totally obfuscated:

https://www.codenameone.com/demos/Restaurant/teavm/classes.js

You can disable this thru the `javascript.minifying=false` build hint covered [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html).